# Visualize decision tree with not only training set tag distribution, but also test set tag distribution

Tags: python, scikit-learn, decision-tree

We can visualize decision tree with training set distribution, for example

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier 
from sklearn import tree

# Prepare the data data, can do row sample and column sample here
iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data
y = iris.target
# Fit the classifier with default hyper-parameters
clf = DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=1234)
clf.fit(X, y)


fig = plt.figure(figsize=(25,20))
_ = tree.plot_tree(clf, 
                   feature_names=iris.feature_names,  
                   class_names=iris.target_names,
                   filled=True)
```

gives us [image]
with distribution of training set, for example `value = [50, 50, 50]` in the root node.

However, I am not able to give it a test set, and get the distribution of test set in the visualized tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is an sklearn method to do this (yet).

**Option 1: Changing the annotation plot of the tree by adding X_test information**

You can use the custom function below:

```
def plot_tree_test(clf, tree_plot, X_test, y_test):

    n = len(tree_plot)
    cat = clf.n_classes_

    # Getting the path for each item in X_test
    path = clf.decision_path(X_test).toarray().transpose()

    # Looping through each node/leaf in the tree and adding information from X_test path
    for i in range(n):
        value = []
        for j in range(cat):
            value += [sum(y_test[path[i]==1]==j)]
        tree_plot[i].set_text(tree_plot[i].get_text()+f'\ntest samples = {path[i].sum()}\ntest value = {value}')
    
    return tree_plot
```

Then changing slightly the script:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier 
from sklearn import tree
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

# Prepare the data data, can do row sample and column sample here
iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data
y = iris.target

# Creating a train and test set
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, shuffle=True, random_state=1234)

# Fit the classifier with default hyper-parameters
clf = DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=1234)
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(25,20))
tree_plot = tree.plot_tree(clf, 
                   feature_names=iris.feature_names,  
                   class_names=iris.target_names,
                   filled=True)

tree_plot = plot_tree_test(clf, tree_plot, X_test, y_test)
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image: Decision Tree 1]

**Option 2: Changing the classifier itself with X_test information**

You can use the custom function below:

```
def tree_test(clf, X_test, y_test):

    state = clf.tree_.__getstate__()
    n = len(state['values'])
    cat = clf.n_classes_
    
    # Getting the path for each item in X_test
    path = clf.decision_path(X_test).toarray().transpose()
    
    # Looping through each node/leaf in the tree and adding information from X_test path
    values = []
    for i in range(n):
        value = []
        for j in range(cat):
            value += [float(sum(y_test[path[i]==1]==j))]
        values += [[value]]
        state['nodes'][i][5] = path[i].sum()
        state['nodes'][i][6] = max(path[i].sum(), 0.1) # 0 returns error
    
    values = np.array(values)
    state['values'] = values
    clf.tree_.__setstate__(state)
    return clf
```

Then changing slightly the script:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier 
from sklearn import tree
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import numpy as np

# Prepare the data data, can do row sample and column sample here
iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data
y = iris.target

# Creating a train and test set
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, shuffle=True, random_state=1234)

# Fit the classifier with default hyper-parameters
clf = DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=1234)
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

clf = tree_test(clf, X_test, y_test)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(25,20))
tree_plot = tree.plot_tree(clf, 
                   feature_names=iris.feature_names,  
                   class_names=iris.target_names,
                   filled=True)

plt.show()
```

Output:

[image: Decision Tree 2]