# Random Forest classifier value is not integer

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest, graphviz, decision-tree

I have trained RF model using binary classification target variable.
As my data is imbalanced, I'm using `class_weight='balanced'` (I saw that it might be the cause, could not find solution for this problem).
When plotting a tree from the model, I get the following output:
[image]

code:

```
import graphviz
from sklearn import tree
import os

# Assuming your Random Forest model is named 'model'
trees = model.estimators_

# Plot the first tree
dot_data = tree.export_graphviz(trees[0], out_file=None, filled=True, rounded=True, special_characters=True) #), feature_names=X_rf.columns)
graph = graphviz.Source(dot_data)
graph
```

When I'm not using `class_weight='balanced'` in the model training, I get the expected behaviour.

I expect to see integer values at the value attribute, like `value = [124, 2145]`,
for each node.

## Edit

I have tried adding proportion=True, as suggested in the comments (The answer I found in the reference to the Github issue).

It's only changing the value from count to proportion. It doesn't solve the issue.

It seems that only multiplying the value by the inverse weight can solve the problem, but I couldn't find an implementation for that (reminder - the problem is only in visualizing the results, not in the performance of the model).

Comment: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/18943

Answer (score 2):

From [the docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.plot_tree.html#sklearn.tree.plot_tree) for `plot_tree`:

> The sample counts that are shown are weighted with any sample_weights that might be present.

That is, those numbers are the total weight of samples of each class. Since your weights are class weights, you can recover the sample counts by just dividing by the corresponding class weight.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!
Can you help me with code example of how to apply the division and be able to plot it using graphviz?

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1: Changing the tree, displaying the values for X_train and y_train**

You can use the following [custom function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71866688/visualize-decision-tree-with-not-only-training-set-tag-distribution-but-also-te/75467252#75467252) to display the tree values for a specific X and y inputs:

```py
def tree_test(clf, X_test, y_test):

    state = clf.tree_.__getstate__()
    n = len(state['values'])
    cat = clf.n_classes_
    
    # Getting the path for each item in X_test
    path = clf.decision_path(X_test).toarray().transpose()
    
    # Looping through each node/leaf in the tree and adding information from X_test path
    values = []
    for i in range(n):
        value = []
        for j in range(cat):
            value += [float(sum(y_test[path[i]==1]==j))]
        values += [[value]]
        state['nodes'][i][5] = path[i].sum()
        state['nodes'][i][6] = max(path[i].sum(), 0.1) # 0 returns error
    
    values = np.array(values)
    state['values'] = values
    clf.tree_.__setstate__(state)
    return clf
```

Then adapting your code:

```py
import graphviz
from sklearn import tree
import os

# Assuming your Random Forest model is named 'model'
trees = model.estimators_

# Plot the first tree
trees[0] = tree_test(trees[0], X_train, y_train)
dot_data = tree.export_graphviz(trees[0], out_file=None, filled=True, rounded=True, special_characters=True) #), feature_names=X_rf.columns)
graph = graphviz.Source(dot_data)
graph
```

Here `X_train` and `y_train` are the input and target you used to train your random forest model.

**Option 2: Dividing the values by the weight**

You can use the following custom function:

```py
def tree_values(clf):

    state = clf.tree_.__getstate__()
    n = len(state['values'])
    
    # Looping through each node/leaf in the tree and changing to unweighted values
    for i in range(n):
        state['values'][i] *= state['nodes'][i][5]/state['nodes'][i][6]

    clf.tree_.__setstate__(state)
    return clf
```

Then adapting your code:

```py
import graphviz
from sklearn import tree
import os

# Assuming your Random Forest model is named 'model'
trees = model.estimators_

# Plot the first tree
trees[0] = tree_values(trees[0])
dot_data = tree.export_graphviz(trees[0], out_file=None, filled=True, rounded=True, special_characters=True) #), feature_names=X_rf.columns)
graph = graphviz.Source(dot_data)
graph
```

This is the same as using `proportion=True` and then multiplying by the number of samples.
You can notice now the sum of the values gives you the total sample at each node, but you might not always get integer values.

Comment: both seems to work! however, the color coding seems to be lost